# Why does using \MakeTextUppercase on \insertsection result in references that are replaced with a fixed one?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, hyperlink, uppercase

OK, here is what I want to do: Change the text case to uppercase only for the section title on a section page. However if I put the `\insertsection` command into `\MakeTextUppercase`, I get the warning `name{NAVIGATION1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`. If I remove the `\MakeTextUppercase` I am getting rid of it, but I also get rid of the uppercase.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{textcase}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytemplate}{\MakeTextUppercase{\insertsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{Conclusions}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the warning and still have uppercase section titles on my section page?

Comment: On my system, your example compiles without issuing a warning.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It happens to me with pdfLaTeX from `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6362 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit)` and `Document Class: beamer 2017/08/22 v3.43 A class for typesetting presentations`

Comment: I used the most recent version of `beamer`: 2020/05/06 v3.58 in combination with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @leandriis OK, unfortunately I am stuck with this version for a while here, but at least there is light for my next internal release. ;-)

Comment: @leandris I get the warning in a current tex system. Did you actually check the log?

Comment: Like Ulrike I can reproduce the warning with `beamer.cls 2020/05/06 v3.58`, `hyperref.sty    2020-05-15 v7.00e` on `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Interesting. The log file indeed contains the mentioned warning. This is indeed one of the cases I got fooled by my editor not showing me the warning. Sorry fo the confusion.

Comment: I'd try and work around this by modifying `\secname` to contain the uppercase section name. But I have no idea about `beamer` and whether this is a viable solution, so I'll post this off-site https://gist.github.com/moewew/7ff45c19a32273320f5d097c3bbb349c

Comment: @moewe I can confirm, that your solution does work on my end without the warning, too. Can you elaborate a bit on what it does, because I always struggle with too many expandafters. ;-) And just to clarify my requirement, the section in my bookmarks shall stay in the original case, I only want to have the text on the actual slide printed in all uppercase. However I also worked a bit and have an answer to my question, can you please check if it makes sense?

Comment: I have no idea if your solution is the standard way to do this in `beamer` or if there is a better interface to do what you want, but it looks sensible if you just follow the involved TeX commands.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, I think there is no build-in interface in beamer for this so if from the LaTeX technical side nothing speaks against it, I stay with my solution. Thanks Ulrike, too for pointing out leandriis overlooked something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue with my setup:

Beamer defines `\insertsection` as `\def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%` and so it takes some expansions in between, before we actually typeset a link!

Now I had a look on `\sectionlink`, which is defined as `{\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%`. Honestly I don't know the TeX magic here, but for sure `\sectionlink` expands to two tokens.

So as far as I see I need to make sure, that the hyperlink is created and the text is converted to uppercase, so I defined a new command `\insertsectionuppercase` and then make use of it.

This is my working result, which produces no more warning:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{textcase}

\newcommand{\insertsectionuppercase}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}}

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{mytemplate}{\expandafter\insertsectionuppercase\sectionlink}

\begin{document}
    \section{Conclusions}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
\end{document}
```